# Custom swipe to delete for rounded TableViewCell with drop shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make a custom swipe to delete style which appears like being behind the cell itself, not side by side like the default trailingSwipeActionsConfiguration.

Something like this:
[image]

Is there any way to create a design like this?
From what I've tried with the default swipe control there will be a gap between the cell itself and the delete button due to the cells padding for drop shadow and also the red color of the delete button needs to extends under rounded corners of the cell.
Also I've tried creating a subview behind the cell when tableview willBeginEditingRowAt is being called but it seems off(sometime works, sometimes doesn't). Perhaps there might be a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you found solution for this ?

Comment: unfortunately, no

Comment: Any luck?  Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes you need to set up custom view for the action element.

One way, less sophisticated, is to add another view of the red colour below the cell's main view and simply set new translation through the custom swipe. For this view you can add corners and the shadow with the

```
tableView.subviews.forEach { view in 
   view.layer.shadow 
    // …
}
```

Another approach, is to create a mask for the action element:

```
func configureMaskFor(size: CGSize) -> CAShapeLayer{
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 9

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    bezierPath.move(to: startPoint)

    let point1 = CGPoint(x: size.width - cornerRadius, y: 0)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: point1)
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: point1.x, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 3), endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)

    let point2 = CGPoint(x: size.width, y: size.height - cornerRadius)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: point2)
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: point1.x, y: point2.y), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2, clockwise: true)


    let point3 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: size.height)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: point3)
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: point3.x, y: point3.y - cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2 , endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)

    let point4 = CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: point4)
    bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2 * 3 , clockwise: false)

    bezierPath.close()

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    return shapeLayer
}
```

And in `layoutSubviews()` add the mask:

```
view.layer.mask = configureMaskFor(size: CGSize(width: contentView.frame.width * 0.2 , height: contentView.frame.height))
```